# "Remember thou shalt die": Shall/will

Tags: translation, latin, will-future, shall-future, shall-will

A common translation of the Latin hortative *memento mori* is "Remember thou shalt die."

I am not interested in a discussion of the Latin, nor of what the expression actually means in English. I am more interested in why English speakers chose the formulation "Remember thou shalt die" over "Remember thou *wilt* die," [considering the implications of "shall" and "will" in English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/shall-or-will).

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/236286/98198) thoroughly correct answer to a similar question definitely implies that "will" would be the right choice. --And yet Google has almost three thousand results for "Remember thou shalt die" (in quotes), and a mere two for "Remember thou wilt die."

Can anyone explain why this is? And: Which form is correct?

Related: [The use of "will" in assumptions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70250/the-use-of-will-in-assumptions)

--

*N.B.: Mentions of "will" in this question refer to the future auxiliary, not to the verb "to will." Separately: I am not interested in answers which assert that "shall" and "will" are practically interchangeable these days.*

Comment: The particular English speakers who composed that line were speakers of Early Modern English, circa 1600; and they were churchmen who were familiar with earlier versions of English and with biblical scholarship in many languages. They chose a construction that was archaic at the time, as they did for many sentences in the KJV; in their opinion (ratified by time), archaic constructions worked better in religious texts. As for the "traditional" implications of _shall_ and _will_, that's a zombie rule; no English speaker ever talked that way, unless badgered by a schoolteacher.

Comment: Could it be that the use of "shall" is an effort to recreate, using a calque from German, a subjunctive/jussive undertone in the Latin? --If so, this is extremely subtle.

Comment: @johnLawler Are you sure this is why "shall" is used in the KJV? I am inclined to doubt it. Forms of "will" are found just as often as "shall," the distinction being that "will" is chosen when it matches the tense/mood of the original. Or so I understand.

Comment: @JohnLawler Also, re: your last sentence--Especially in writing, I indeed make an effort to use "shall" as the future auxiliary for the first person. The zombie shall not die!

Comment: *And death shall be no more; **Death, thou shalt die!*** Holy Sonnet X
by John Donne - http://rjgeib.com/thoughts/proud/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Shakespeare, *shall* and *will* were not used according to the "traditional rule in Standard British English" described in your link. You can see from [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+shall%2CI+will+&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20shall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20will%3B%2Cc0) that there was a big change in the rules for *shall* and *will* between 1600 and 1700, at least for first person. Since the comments say this line was composed around 1600, the grammar would presumably be that of Shakespeare.

As far as I can tell from looking at examples in Shakespeare, for people he used *will* to indicate volition on the part of the actor, and *shall* to indicate lack of volition. Thus, *thou shalt die* means you are dying without necessarily wanting to.

EDIT: I have found a reference for this usage. From [The Cambridge History of the English Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=CCvMbntWth8C&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=modals+in+early+modern+english+will+shall+intention&source=bl&ots=U1A0URpGFa&sig=WdiW4Gh3bkP5t6jLsL821CYz_o4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM3cmqgtfMAhVINT4KHVKvAbEQ6AEIVzAJ#v=onepage&q=modals%20in%20early%20modern%20english%20will%20shall%20intention&f=false):

> It has been suggested (e.g. (Jespersen MEG IV 18.1; Strang 1970: 206) that the divided use of the two auxiliaries to indicate future time might go back to the model set by the Wycliffite Bible translation, which used *shall* for unmarked and *will* for volitionally marked future. This practice would have been copied by the schools in their translation exercises. This theory certainly gives a much simplified picture of the development; yet it seems that *will* developed its pure (predictive) future use later than *shall*, in colloquial speech, as a `change from below'.
>
> The peculiar pattern of distribution in which *shall* is the future auxiliary used with the first-person subject while *will* is used in the second and third persons can be first traced in Early Modern English. The grammarian Mason first states this rule in 1622, and Wallis in 1635 (Visser §1433) but the tendency can be traced in texts as early as the 16th century.

Comment: Wikipedia kind of mentions non-volitional "shall" in the second and third persons: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_and_will#Uses_of_shall_and_will_in_expressing_futurity

Comment: The Pragmatics of Modals in Shakespeare. https://books.google.it/books?id=ICHnbeG81bsC&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=middle+english+shall+and+will&source=bl&ots=uqmoYsKPCV&sig=dwbowKVoGX9J1ciGnMOAP_ZqWoo&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz7ILs49TMAhUKApoKHZj9BWoQ6AEIZTAI#v=onepage&q=middle%20english%20shall%20and%20will&f=false

Comment: This is correct. The two words come from Old English *willan* 'to wish' and *sculan* 'to owe, be obliged'.

Comment: I may agree about Shakespeare, but the use of shall/will in my sentence is not the same as its use in the KJV: The KJV uses shall/will ~according to the current conventions. (Indeed, it may have invented these.)

Comment: @Anonym Also, "to will" (Old English "willian") is being conflated in this discussion with "will" (Old English "willan"), the future auxiliary. These are not the same verb--although, as noted, they may share some aspects of meaning.

Comment: @SAH: apart from a change in the grammar, what else could have caused people to switch from *I will* to *I shall* in such large numbers?

Comment: @SAH: Indeed, I have found a reference stating that the change from volitional *will* and non-volitional *shall* to 2nd and 3rd-person *will* and 1st person *shall* started in the 16th century; from my Ngram, it wasn't complete until the end of the 17th. So both Shakespeare and the King James Bible were written very close to the start of this transition.

Comment: @SAH: Who is conflating them? They are distinct verbs, but they're related etymologically, and they used to have similar meanings.

Comment: @PeterShor Nice work; thanks. Separately, if you were writing a paper in which you wanted an English translation of "memento mori" that were at once standard and correct, which would you choose?

Comment: Googling, it seems like the most common contemporary English translations are "remember that you will die" and "remember that you must die". These mean pretty much the same thing in English. Which is more correct as a translation of the Latin? Literally, probably the first, since the Latin just uses the infinitive and there's nothing that translates to *"must"*.

Comment: @PeterShor I need an old-school literary flavor in my context, so it's really between "Remember thou shalt die" and "Remember thou wilt die." Which would you use? (I'm aware the first one is standard, but I'm worried it will look incorrect)

Comment: @SAH: I think the relevant question is: what percentage of your audience still use the traditional 1st person–shall; 2nd & 3rd person–will distinction. These are the people who might get confused. The percentage is essentially zero in the U.S., but might be larger in the U.K. I actually think either would work fine.

Comment: @PeterShor -- "Use": zero; "are aware of": significant numbers. But then, they might also be aware of the "standard" translation of this phrase--or they might not. Trying to find out which way would look wrong to the fewest educated people >>

Comment: @PeterShor Oh, and in case this could be some kind of tiebreaker: I'm going to use it in a negative construction, so "Remember thou shalt not die" or "Remember thou wilt not die." Ideas?